# broken links and images in search engine cached pages only

Tags: web-services, .htaccess

I got a weird problem, my site shows up perfectly in all browsers but when checking cached pages of site in Google, Bing or even Yahoo,  all of them shows broken links and images because some links are overridden such as

Let's say direct url is http://www.expatads.com/47-Thailand/ and it shows perfect.

Here's google cache of the same url.
http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:qFAzM4VMsJsJ:www.expatads.com/47-Thailand/+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk

What I want to know is the best way to reproduce such errors that are visible instead of waiting for search engines to cache and show pages. Since web browsers do not show any error but actually there is path error that cause that.

I'll appreciate if anyone can give me a way that I can reproduce these errors using some browser, software or whatever?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are mistaken about this being an error. If you take a look at the screenshot of [Google's search result for your page](https://www.google.com/#hl=en&sclient=psy-ab&q=expatads.com%2F47-Thailand%2F&oq=expatads.com%2F47-Thailand%2F), the images are shown.

It appears that Google's cache does not rewrite relative URLs, which makes some sense because it wouldn't always work and some sites might not allow hotlinking, etc. So, all the the resources linked to on your page using relative links won't show up in Google's cached version.

If you would rather see what your site looks like in other browsers you may want to try [Browsershots](http://browsershots.org/). This will give you screenshots from a huge number of browsers in order to test compatibility.